# Running parallel docker builds gives an error message -> Error removing intermediate container <id>: container <id>: driver "windowsfilter" failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

Running parallel docker builds sometimes gives an error message:

```
Error removing intermediate container <id>: container <id>: driver
"windowsfilter" failed to remove root filesystem: hcsshim::GetComputeSystems:
Access is denied.
```

Note: `<id>` is the hash value

For example - say this error message comes at the end of step 3 in docker file. Then, at the end of the each subsequent command in the dockerfile, it re-tries to remove the intermediate container that it failed to remove in the previous step(s) along with removing any container from the current step. Sometimes it may succeed. Either ways - it does not stop the build process. However if the process is not able to remove a container by end of the build process, then this results in a container (inactive) and an image (dangled) resulting in waste of disk space.

1. What is the reason for this behaviour?
2. I know that `docker container prune -f` and `docker image prune -f` can be used to clean-up containers and images respectively. But is there any other solution to resolve this error message and inactive container/dangled image during parallel builds?
3. Does docker have any limitations with regards to running parallel builds?

Comment: I think things would be simpler if you were to run a single `docker image prune` after all pipelines completed.

Comment: I am facing this issue even when not using `prune` during build. I have updated the question now.

Comment: @variable Just wondering, do you use `buildkit` as a backend for your builds?

Comment: No. I am using a build machine with multiple agents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this branch here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36218
It seems one of the active drivers might prevent renaming / deleting files, like the Cisco AMP (ImmunetProtectDriver). You might want to check and deactivate it or any other ones. Another suggestion on that branch was to run Docker without the `-it` flags unless you really want them.